# Bootstrap icons are not displayed well

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Im having MVC5 application and I use the following button to display icon from bootstrap to it.the problem is that the icon are not displyed well(all the icons that I tested having the same issue..),I see just rectangle instead of icon garbage can,**Im already use it in diffrent project and it works well**,in the contnet folder I've the bootstrap.css & bootstrap.min.css.I think that maybe I miss some file, which are the things which I should verify that are exist in the project ?or other suggestion....

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the font files?

Comment: what is the font file,we are working on this project like 2-3 person so how should I know if it exist or not?should I add it?if yes how and from where?

Comment: In the middle of your files you should have a folder called fonts or something like that, and then you must have glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot ,glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Comment: If you have the font files on your server, then i bet that the problem should be the path to the files. Are you seeing bordered squares instead of the icons?

Comment: "Are you seeing bordered squares instead of the icons?" Yes you are, LOL, i rode with more attention your problem!!! In your browser console are you having errors such as file not found or something like that?

Comment: HI legues no I dont have the errors,from where should I take this ?glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot ,glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff ,and how should I put them into my project?

Comment: I´m trying to understand John´s problem!!! And i believe the problem will be solved when he download the fonts.